# What does this mean symbol mean

Tags: translation

Sorry the pic is not clear, I got this tattoo over 15 years ago, I did a lot of research before hand when getting it, but now I can't for the life of me remember what it is. I know the symbol on the bottom is "Love" . I am planning on getting it touched up since it as faded.

[image]

Comment: Think he means read it bottom to top is 爱需，you should rotate the photo 90 clockwise if you want to read left to right. All you need is love! Where does the name Kaeskia come from?

Comment: `需爱`, `need to love`? `need to be loved`?

Answer (score 2):

You could have shown a little more research effort.

The characters are 愛 ai and 需 xu. Ai means love, xu means need.

You could read it right to left and get xu'ai, "need love" (verb + object), or you go left to right and get ai xu, which I'd read as two single words "love and need". I'm sorry to say that in both cases, it doesn't make much sense to me. It could, of course, be a transliteration of a name or something similar.